# Open ball is not equal to its convex hull

Tags: geometry

In my lecture note of geometry class, there's an application of Krein-Milman theorem said: An open ball has no extreme points and it is not equal to its convex hull. Note that $\Delta$ is not closed. A half-space $\Delta$ has no extreme points and it is not equal to its convex hull. Note that $\Delta$ is not bounded.

I don't understand why convex hull of open ball/half space are not equal to their convex hulls? Isn't by definition open ball/half space are convex, so their convex hulls are just themselves?

> Theorem 2.4.3 (*Finite dimensional Krein-Milman theorem*). Let $\Delta\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded convex closed set. Then the set $E\subset\Delta$ of all extreme points in $\Delta$ is the smallest subset in $\Delta$ whose convex hull is $\Delta$. In other words, the convex hull $\Delta(S)$ of a set $S\subset\Delta$ is equal to $\Delta$ if and only if $S \supset E$.

> Definition 2.3.3. The convex hull $\Delta(S)$ of the set $S$ is the smallest convex set that contains $S$. It can be described also as the intersection of all convex sets that contain $S$.

> Definition 2.1.1. Let $L$ be a real affine space (for example a plane, a space, or the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which the origin is not specified). A subset $X \subset L$ is convex if with any two points $A, B \in X$ it contains the segment $[A, B]$ joining them.

[image]

Comment: Disregard that sentence from your notes: every convex subset equals it's own convex hull.

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly what your lectures notes said? I suspect that the intention was to give examples to illustrate that the hypotheses in Krein-Milman theorem are needed - ie an example of a non-closed convex set and an unbounded convex set, both of which are not the convex hull of the set of their extreme points. The point is that the open ball is not the convex hull *of the set of its extreme points*, which is empty.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I added an image of the lecture note. I am very confused about it.

Comment: Fair enough! That is very unclearly written. Perhaps this is an anomaly that was overlooked while editing. I am now very confident that my suspicion is correct. This isn't meant to be an application of the theorem, but an example to show the conclusion of theorem failing when its hypotheses aren't satisfied. If you replace "... equal to its convex hull" by "... equal to the convex hull of the set $E$ of its extreme points", does it make sense to you? I think it's worth contacting whoever wrote these notes to politely let them know about this, if that's possible.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you very much! Those examples make sense now!